# Differences between serendipity, and fate, destiny, fortune and coincidence?

Tags: differences

What are the differences between serendipity, fate, destiny, fortune and coincidence?

Serendipity is similar to fate and destiny in that the occurrence is controlled by some "god" or some unforeseen force.

Serendipity seems similar to fortune and coincidence in that the occurrence is accidental, not controlled by people.

Comment: What did the dictionary say? More importantly, where do you think they are similar or perhaps too similar?

Comment: I added some thoughts

Comment: *Serendipity* is "happy accident".  No "god" or "unseen force" involved.  Closer to "coincidence" than it is to your other terms.

Answer (score 2):

Fate: Predetermined events, with implications of some underlying plan or logic.  Generally used in relationship to larger events, often has supernatural undertones.

Coincidence:  Two things lining up by meaningless chance.

Serendipity:  Lucky or positive coincidence.

Destiny:  Typically implying big and positive things fated for a given individual, although all those modifiers are optional.

Fortune: Typically means good luck, although there are overlaps with serendipity, fate and destiny.